# How to really see the contents of the different perl scripts linking to one file?

Tags: perl, unix, konsole

I wanted to view the contents of a perl script in our environment which is called `dfv_run.pl` and specifically check line 245. Line 245 from that script printed the message "Finished checking test result" in my simulation log file. After executing `% which dfv_run.pl` I am pointed to this location:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 dfvmgr dfvadmin 4.0K Jun 22  2017 .SYNC
-r--r--r-- 1 dfvmgr dfvadmin 3.2K Jun 22  2017 loadenv.csh
-r-xr-xr-x 1 dfvmgr dfvadmin 5.2K Jun 22  2017 loadenv
drwxr-xr-x 4 dfvmgr dfvadmin 4.0K Jun 22  2017 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 dfvmgr dfvadmin 4.0K Jun 22  2017 .
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dfvmgr dfvadmin    7 Jun 22  2017 dfv_comp.pl -> loadenv
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dfvmgr dfvadmin    7 Jun 22  2017 dfv_run.pl -> loadenv
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dfvmgr dfvadmin    7 Jun 22  2017 dfv_sim.pl -> loadenv
/tools/dfv/scripts/v11/bin
```

However the script is only less than 200 lines and I can see the same content for `dfv_comp.pl`, `dfv_run.pl`, and `dfv_sim.pl` (also `diff` did not show any difference among the 3 perl scripts). `loadenv` of course also showed me the same contents.

Any help as to how I can view the real content of each perl script is much appreciated. Additional info which might help:

```
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE=:1.46
KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW=/Windows/17
KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION=/Sessions/30
```

Kindly let me know if additional info is needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You’re going to need to show the full actual output, and possibly the source of loadenv too. Chances are VERY high that loadenv calls other scripts, and one of those has a line 245 which is printing that.

Comment: I was slowly progressing based on your answers. At first ```loadenv``` is full of environment variable settings so I didn't pay much attention. Towards the very end of the code, there's a system call ```my $cmd = qq(tcsh -fc "source $bin_path/loadenv.csh @my_args");``` which leads me to ```loadenv.csh```. That script also has a bunch of variable settings and again near the bottom of the code there's a ```$PATH``` variable that contains several locations. Upon checking one path which makes sense for my purpose (i.e. verification), I finally saw the actual scripts used. Thank you very much!

Comment: As additional learning, any reason behind why the scripts are structured in this way?

Comment: Usually it’s for code reuse and abstraction. Most people today use Bash (or zsh on Macs), but I’m a tcsh user like you. `loadenv` probably needs to detect your shell so that it can call the correct script, like loadenv.csh for you, which probably needs to set other things up in the context of YOUR shell, not the script’s shell/process. The multi-level loading and that same-source-code-but-called-by-different-names are a little common, especially in Linux/Unix apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing *is* the real content.  All three `*.pl` filenames are aliases to the `loadenv` script - that one script handles all four commands.

If you look at the contents of `loadenv` (or any of the other three names), you will most likely see that it checks to see which name was used to invoke it and then sets some flags which will cause it to behave differently depending on which name was used.